# React client has trouble properly distributing received ActionCable broadcast

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redux, react-redux, actioncable

On both browsers, my chat app works as expected for 2-3 rounds of messaging. Afterwards, I get the same message appear many many times on Safari, yet on Chrome my problem is that messaging stops entirely.

---

UPDATE:

Since originally posting my question, I tried logging into Safari and Chrome in reverse order. When I do this, the problem actually switches. In the console I see that whichever browser was logged into the chatroom second will receive 2 or more instances of the broadcast, while the user who logged in first will receive no messages.

---

I initially had trouble receiving the broadcast at all, but resolved it by using the npm package react-actioncable-provider. My question and answer to that can be found here: [Cannot access data from ActionCable on React front-end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55283066/cannot-access-data-from-actioncable-on-react-front-end)

I have tested with my cable.yml adapter set to redis, postgresql, and async. As expected, async does not work at all. The same problem happens whether I use redis or postgresql as my adapter.

I am developing and testing on a MacBook Air. My ruby version is 2.6.2, and my rails version is 5.2.2.

Here is my messages_channel.rb:

```
class MessagesChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    @game = Game.find(params[:game_id])
    stream_for @game
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

This is the create function within my messages_controller.rb:

```
  def create
    @game = Game.find(message_params[:game_id])
    @message = Message.new(message_params)
    if @message.save
      serialized_data = ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::Json.new(
        MessageSerializer.new(@message)
      ).serializable_hash
      puts "serialized_data"
      MessagesChannel.broadcast_to @game, serialized_data
    end
  end
```

Here is my client-side code written in react using redux:

```
import { ActionCable } from 'react-actioncable-provider';
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class Cable extends Component {

  render () {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <ActionCable
          key={this.props.game_id}
          channel={{ channel: "MessagesChannel", game_id: this.props.game_id }}
          onReceived={(data) => {
            console.log("MessagesChannel recvd data: ",data)
            this.props.getMessages(data.message)
          }}
        />
    </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { state }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getMessages: data => dispatch({ type: "UP_MSG", payload: data })
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cable);
```

What happens when my client successfully receives broadcasted data from actioncable, is that my reducer is called with the action.type "UP_MSG". Inside of that switch case, I have a console.log and can see in Chrome & Safari that it is not just that messages aren't being displayed, but that messages aren't being received after a certain period of time. On the browser receiving multiple messages, I can see the console.log from inside my "UP_MSG" case in my reducer appear as many times as the message appears.

I don't see any difference in the backend output in the terminal. Because that behavior is the same, and because both browsers have different errors, my thought is that the problem must be on the client.

Even if you don't have an answer, any helpful thoughts on debugging would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading this far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although at first I was fairly certain it was a front end issue, it turns out that I was mistaken. I first had a clue that it may be a performance issue when I step away from my laptop for a minute, and found that all messages did indeed transmit to the "silent" browser window, it just happened quite slowly.

Searching my backend code, I couldn't find anything in particular that should slow performance so much. Especially as I am working in a demo branch with only one group chat room and no need to sort through where what belongs.

While searching, I found this article: https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/anycable-actioncable-on-steroids

That led me to the docs for anycable-rails on github: https://github.com/anycable/anycable-rails

Installing anycable-go via brew on my MacBook Air, then following the steps provided in the anycable-rails docs to add the gem to my rails backend worked for me.

Once I had anycable-rails configured and installed, I ceased to have problems with my app.